# .Net Core 3 Blazor Server - How to do basic login with claims?

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

I already have tables with usernames, passwords, and role IDs, so I do not want to use the ASP.NET Membership tables.  And I only need a simple login page that asks for username and password, not their pre-built Identity.UI package.

But I do not know how to get Blazor Server to do a basic login for me.  I have what I believe should be the basics configured in Startup.cs, such as:

In ConfigureServices:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie();
```

In Configure():

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Normally I would call something like this:

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
    principal, 
    new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = loginData.RememberMe });
```

And in fact the above **does** work if I run it from a .cshtml page, but I want this to work as a Blazor component (.razor).

I tried injecting `httpContextAccessor` but trying to call the `SignInAsync` method from there resulted in an error about the headers already being set.

I have a .razor Login component which I don't know what to call to do an actual sign in.

```
@page "/login"


@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
@using System.Security.Claims;


@inject NavigationManager navigationManager
@inject DataAccess.Models.CurrentDataContext db

<h3>Login</h3>

<div>
    Email:
    <input type="text" @bind="@email" />
</div>

<div>
    Password:
    <input type="text" @bind="@password" />
</div>

<div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="DoLogin">Log In</button>
    <span class="text-danger">@loginErrorMessage</span>
</div>

@code {
    string email = "";
    string password = "";
    string loginErrorMessage = "";

    protected async Task DoLogin()
    {
        var emailTrimmed = email.ToLower().Trim();
        var user = db.UserAccount.FirstOrDefault(u => u.EmailAddress.ToLower() == emailTrimmed);
        if (user != null) //if (user != null)
        {

            //TODO check password


            var claims = new List<Claim> { 
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, emailTrimmed)
            };

            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);


            //SIGN in the user

            ///////////////////////////
            //   WHAT GOES HERE?   ////
            ///////////////////////////
            //

            navigationManager.NavigateTo("/fetchdata");

        }
        else
        {
            loginErrorMessage = "Error logging in.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be worth you while to check out some of these projects to get you going:  https://github.com/AdrienTorris/awesome-blazor#sample-projects

Answer (score 5):

I made a version, which is based on this guy's post:
https://www.oqtane.org/Resources/Blog/PostId/527/exploring-authentication-in-blazor?fbclid=IwAR0rbQkY47cHHxs29HWCk0RggH7GHeLDx3kJ4vwmgUGMTsFU3hxpsQ9ybZo

Honestly, I made very little of my project myself, but mostly stole what I needed from the oqtane post above.

And I think he based his project on Michael's answer above.

I have the project on git (First time using git, I committed way too much, it's currently a bit messy):
https://github.com/TroelsMortensen/DNP/tree/master/Blazor/JSLogin

I must admit I'm not entirely sure, what I'm doing. And it's not finished. Right now there's no check against user database or actual validation or whatever. And the claims are hardcoded. But that should be easy to implement. 
I needed something super simple, cookie authentication, without Identity. With this approach I control almost everything myself.
I have a javascript (again, not really mine) which can send post requests to a razor page, I think.

The Pages/Account/Login.razor sends a call to Shared/Interop.cs to make it use the javascript in wwwroot/interop.js to call the post method in Pages/Account/LoginRequester.cshtml.cs. I think.

I include the interop.js in the Pages/_Host.cshtml to get access to it

I use the HttpContext to sign in.
The LoginDisplay.razor is inserted into Shared/MainLayout.razor.

Comment: I actually made a new, slightly simpler version, which do not use requests. I implement a custom AuthenticationStateProvider, in this example here:
https://github.com/TroelsMortensen/DNPExamples/tree/master/Blazor/LoginExample

Answer (score 3):

As I cover in:
[A Demonstration of Simple Server-side Blazor Cookie Authentication](http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4316/A-Demonstration-of-Simple-Server-side-Blazor-Cookie-Authentication.aspx)

You can log a person in with the following code in a .cshtml file:

```
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    public async Task<IActionResult> 
        OnGetAsync(string paramUsername, string paramPassword)
    {
        string returnUrl = Url.Content("~/");
        try
        {
            // Clear the existing external cookie
            await HttpContext
                .SignOutAsync(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
        catch { }
        // *** !!! This is where you would validate the user !!! ***
        // In this example we just log the user in
        // (Always log the user in for this demo)
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, paramUsername),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"),
        };
        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
            claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            IsPersistent = true,
            RedirectUri = this.Request.Host.Value
        };
        try
        {
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
            authProperties);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
}
```

As to logging the person in in a .razor page, don't worry about that. You have to perform a full post back to establish the authentication cookie. a .razor pages doesn't have a 'post back' but a .cshtml page does.

Comment: This was what I ended up doing to get it to work, and it does seem to work fine.  But my gut was that there must be a more "Blazor" solution that probably looks like what @enet suggested above.  But as yet I've not been able to find any actual source examples of the mystery Blazor way.

Comment: @FirstDivision - Do you want to mark this as the answer?

Comment: Is there no way to do this with a post request? It seems like a hack to use the OnGet..?

Comment: Pretty sure this does login using GET, which is insecure. Troel's answer links an article where it's done with POST.